# Power BI Error: Alternate credentials for Windows authentication is not supported in DirectQuery mode

Tags: powerbi

I have a problem when i want to use DirectQuery. I have a DomainController with installed SQL Server. I have installed Data Gateway and must modify the Service Account to Local System to be able to finish setup. i have setup the Data Gateway successfully in Enterprise Mode. In PowerBi.com everything looks fine and can see the Gateway and no errors.

When i now create a new File with a SQL connection and Mode "Import" and publish it to PowerBi.com, then it works fine and when i schedule a refresh, this works fine, too.

But i want to use DirectQuery on a Database table for example. For this scenario i have created a new Power BI File and selected the same database which i already created as DataSet in PowerBI.com under my Gateway. Then i load the data in the file and while trying to load it i am always receiving the following error message:

> Create Connections
>
> Alternate credentials for Windows authentication is
> not supported in DirectQuery mode. Use your current windows
> credentials, supply a database credential or switch to import mode.

In PowerBI.com under Gateways and Data source i have used Windows Authentication and used the Administrator account which has also permission on the Database. I dont know what this message means and i should change. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2):

it seems that your have a credential problem, I suggest you to go to File->Options and settings->Data source settings, then edit your data source [Edit Permissions...] and specify a valid Windows credential or database credential. After that, click "Refresh" button in the PBIX file.

Hope that helps!

Comment: No, sorry doesnt help. No permission problems cause i can load the dat already through load method but it dors not work just with Direct Query mode.

Comment: This worked - thanks! I ended up having to edit my windows credential and telling PBI to use my current credentials. For some reason alternate was selected.

Comment: If you cant open the PBIX file at all what can you do?

Comment: i cannot open my pbix file to edit the option

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot open the PBIX file, restart Power BI designer with an empty one and then go to the File, Options as explained above. You will find out that an "alternate" credential has been stored for your data source. Use your current credentials instead. Now, try to open the original PBIX file and it you will see that now Direct Query mode works.